# Checking if Matrix fields are empty or not?

Tags: matrix

In a Matrix field i want to check if block.logolink (simple text) **OR** block.logolinkDropdown (dropdown with empty field) are empty or not:

```
{% if block.logolink or block.logolinkDropdown %}
```

If i check them with {{ block.fieldHandle }} they're empty. But still it passes the condition.

Where's my mistake in this statement?

```
{% for block in entry.logomatrix %}
{% switch block.type %}

{% case "logo" %}
{% if block.logobild %}
    {% for logo in block.logobild %}
    {% if block.logolink or block.logolinkDropdown %}
        {% if block.internerLink %}
            <a href={{ block.logolink }}{{ block.logolinkDropdown }}>
        {% else %}
            <a href={{ block.logolink }}{{ block.logolinkDropdown }} TARGET="_blank">
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ logo.getUrl('logogross')}}" data-lightbox="image" data-title="{{ block.logobeschreibung }}"></a>
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% case "textbutton" %}     
...

{% endswitch %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you try Twig's length filter?

Comment: Yes, i tried the length filter first. It ouputs a 0 for the "block.logolink" and a 1 for the "block.logolinkDropdown", altough a empty field is chosen in the  dropdown.

Comment: And how about block.logolinkDropdown.value|length?

Comment: That's the solution! It explains also some other questions i had. Thank you very much rostockahoi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a dropdown field's selected value by using `entry.fieldhandle.value`. So `if entry.fieldhandle.value|length` should do the trick. I think you can even omit the `length` filter in this case, as if you do it with the plain text field. Both an empty string and the length of an empty string resolve to `false`.